# Is it possible to flip an Analog value in Chisel?

Tags: chisel

I'm trying to share an analog value and it's flipped value between two blackbox module, but  `~` and `!` aren't members of `Analog`

How would we flip an Analog signal's value in chisel? I don't think width would be a problem since my analog values have a width of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chisel only supports `Analog` as a port type and connecting/attaching/soldering two `Analog` Wires or Ports together. If you want to do anything else (eg. logic, tristate driving), you need to do it in a BlackBox.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of is generating the flipped value internally in the Verilog Blackbox.